# How DFS time complexity is O(n) since we need to visit a node twice?

Tags: tree, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search

In DFS, we visit a node then explore it's connected node, before exploring other node we first explore the previous one.

We need a stack here because once we explored a node's left then we have to explore its right node. So how time complexity is O(n) since we are visting a node twice to traverse its right child.

I am using DFS to traverse a tree data structure.

Comment: I see you have the habit of never marking an answer as accepted. Could you tell us why? Did all your questions receive bad answers??

Answer (score 2):

> So how time complexity is O() since we are visiting a node twice

A constant factor, like 2 ("twice"), is not relevant when determining time complexity. Let's say that the first visit of a node costs 1ms, and the second also 1ms, then combined it takes 2ms. That is still a constant unit of time that is not dependent on . In fact on different computers you will get different durations, but what is common, is that they don't depend on , and are rather constant.

In short: O(2) is still O() (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant)).